# how to set a string resource using wpf , .net4 and windows 8

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources

When I set a string resource in a WPF application in the window.xaml file I get an error. I have coded like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <sys:String x:Key="strHelloWorld">Hello, world!</sys:String>
</Window.Resources>
```

I'm using ms visual studio 2010 and windows 8. What did I do wrong ?

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include namespace as well:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```